# How to filter a query result?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Currently I can not quickly filter the result of a work-item query - running a query will give us a result table and within this table, there's no mean to filter the table rows to display just the ones containing some certain text.

Do you know how to filter that or have any addons/tools suggestion for that? 
Thank you.

Nam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(similar problem with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235069/how-to-browse-the-work-items-more-quickly2.))

I re-post the answer here:
After a long time, today I found the solution for this: use the MS VS 2010 Team Web Access to open your queries using a web browser!

Advantage when doing this:

1. No delay when clicking an item
2. Utilize all browser feature like searching, bookmark, ... to work with the queries

Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

You could use 
[Telerik's free Work Item Manager](http://www.telerik.com/team-productivity-tools/tfsmanager-and-tfsdashboard/tfs-work-item-manager-features.aspx) .  It lets you search the text of work items as well as other useful filtering and grouping tools.  Very useful.

Comment: Thanks Col. I've tried that and it fit my need. But at the moment this tool do not "understand" the query which has the result containing linked work items.

Answer (score 1):

We use Excel integration pretty heavily in our shop.  The familiar sort and filter controls work well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

You can "Edit Query" from the toolbox and save it as a new query.

Comment: Hi Raj,
Well it is actually what we have to do right now. But it's not good enought. You know, when we search for something, we think of the words to search, and those words may change - which means we often filter more than once. When we edit the current query, we have to re-edit the query to return to the original result.

Answer (score 0):

After a while (long :) ), I luckily notice that there's a filter box if we browse the work items in the pending changes pane (open in VS 2010: View - Other Windows - Pending Changes). It's so nice that now I can quickly get the exact items I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Today, I found an addon that may fit my need: [Search Work Items for TFS 2010](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/3f31bfff-5ecb-4e05-8356-04815851b8e7)
It is a search box, not exactly the filter for the current query.