# How to browse the work items more quickly?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs-workitem

I have to update the work-items of my team very often. But since my office is in a different country from the other team members, the browsing process is very inconvenient: every time I click a work-item, my Visual Studio (VS) tries to connect to the TFS server, costing me 1-2 seconds! I want VS to stop this behavior so that no connection is called while I am browsing the work-tem list.

My question is: Can I do this? And how to do it if I can?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, today I found the solution for this: use the MS VS 2010 Team Web Access to open your queries using a web browser!

Advantage when doing this:

1. No delay when clicking an item
2. Utilize all browser feature like searching, bookmark, ... to work with the queries

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to open the work item query in Microsoft Excel - then you can view and update the work items without being connected to the server.